# How to assign url parameter value and load in iframe using radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html

Using select/option tag works fine but no success when I use radio buttons.

```js
function xxx(){
 var base_url = 'https://example.com/?test=';
 var select_value = document.getElementById('myid').value;
 var target_url = base_url + select_value;
 var ifr = document.getElementById('myiframe');
 ifr.src = target_url;
 return false;
}
```

```html
    <form>
      <select id="myid" onchange="xxx();">
        <option value="VALUE1">Featured</option>
        <option value="VALUE2">Hey</option>
        <option value="VALUE3">Wish</option>
      </select>
    </form>
<iframe src="" id="myiframe" width="460" height="300"></iframe>
```

I want to use below format but the result is "undefined"...

```
<form id="myid" onchange="xxx();">
  <input type="radio" name="name1" value="VALUE1"> featured<br>
  <input type="radio" name="name1" value="VALUE2"> hey<br>
  <input type="radio" name="name1" value="VALUE3"> wish
</form>
```

I'm getting this

> https://example.com/?test=UNDEFINED

instead of

> https://example.com/?test=VALUE1 or VALUE2 or VALUE3

Comment: Could you be more specific on the result, where is showing 'undefined'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use formdata together with the get method to get the form's value like this:

```js
function xxx(){
 let data = new FormData(document.querySelector('form'))
 var base_url = 'https://example.com/?test=';
 var target_url = base_url + data.get('name1');
 var ifr = document.getElementById('myiframe');
 console.log(target_url);
 ifr.src = target_url;
 return false;
}
```

```html
 <form id="myid" onchange="xxx();">
  <input type="radio" name="name1" value="VALUE1"> featured<br>
  <input type="radio" name="name1" value="VALUE2"> hey<br>
  <input type="radio" name="name1" value="VALUE3"> wish
</form>
<iframe src="" id="myiframe" width="460" height="300"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not a PRO in JavaScript but I think it is working

```js
function xxx(){
 var base_url = 'https://example.com/?test=';
 var select_value = document.getElementById('myid').value;
 var target_url = base_url + select_value;
 var ifr = document.getElementById('myiframe');
 ifr.src = target_url;
 return false;
}
```

```html
<form>
      <select id="myid" onchange="xxx();">
        <option value="VALUE1">Featured</option>
        <option value="VALUE2">Hey</option>
        <option value="VALUE3">Wish</option>
      </select>
      
    </form>
    
    <form>
    <input type="radio" id="myid" onchange="xxx();" name="value" value="value1">
<label for="value1">Featured</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="myid" onchange="xxx();" name="value" value="value2">
<label for="value2">Hey</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="myid" onchange="xxx();" name="value" value="value3">
<label for="value3">Wish</label></form>


<iframe src="" id="myiframe" width="460" height="300"></iframe>
```

Comment: When you are using radio-type inputs, you think of at least 2 inputs related to a particular theme / subject. For example, 'are you a man or a woman?', So in this case it is interesting to think about this input, because the person must be only one of these genders, so if you select woman then the input with a man value should be unchecked, but if you select man the woman value has to be cleared, but what will make the previous input cleared? It will be the name attribute that will do this, so it is important to make these inputs that deal with the same theme have the same name, ...

Comment: In your example it is possible to mark the 3 inputs because the name of each one is different

Comment: @AksJacove, yep, you are right, made that by mistake, thanks for you response

Comment: Good to have helped ^^

Comment: Is it more ideal to use the "a" tag?

Comment: @88willr 
The <a> tag defines a hyperlink, which is used to link from one page to another and the <input> tag specifies an input field where the user can enter data.

Comment: Thanks sir! I should have asked <ul> instead of radio button, I just realized I have a long list and it's easier to style as well..hope u can still help.

Comment: @88willr,  <ul>  is not form element so you cannot use that. [More info about form elements that you can use](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp)