# Get <li> value and assign to url parameter in iframe using jquery onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's a question related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62077373/how-to-assign-url-parameter-value-and-load-in-iframe-using-radio-buttons).

From

```
<ul id="myid">
    <li value="VALUE1">featured</li>
    <li value="VALUE2">hey</li>
    <li value="VALUE3">wish</li>
<ul>
<iframe src="" id="myiframe" width="460" height="300"></iframe>
```

To

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/test?=VALUE1 or VALUE2 or VALUE3" id="myiframe" width="460" height="300"></iframe>
```

onclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
you can use like this 
<ul id="myid">
  <li class ="get" value="VALUE1">featured</li>
  <li class ="get" value="VALUE2">hey</li>
  <li class ="get" value="VALUE3">wish</li>
<ul>
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".get").click(function(){
    data = $(this).attr('value');
    url = "http://example.com/test?=";
    $('#myiframe').attr('src', url+data);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @88willr try to put alert or console data variable and (url + data) are you not getting output?

Comment: there is no output.

Comment: did you include jquery library?

Comment: if not added try to include library first , like <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @88willr i updated my answer , i added cdn link for jquery library .

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<ul id="myid">
    <li onclick="myFunction('VALUE1')" value="VALUE1">featured</li>
    <li onclick="myFunction('VALUE2')" value="VALUE2">hey</li>
    <li onclick="myFunction('VALUE1')" value="VALUE3">wish</li>
</ul>
<iframe src="" id="myiframe" width="460" height="300"></iframe>

<script>
    var myURL = 'http://example.com/';

    function myFunction(value) {
        document.getElementById("myiframe").src = myURL + "test?=" + value;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. It worked even without the "value" attribute. Do we have other approach without including the myfunction in the tag?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to achieve this. You can check the other answer if you don't wish to include myfunction in the tag  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62078819/11259696. And accept the answer if it is working for you.